# Mariadb Vs MySql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Recientemente realice la migracion de una pagina a otro servidor.  Empece a observar un extraño comportamiento de un modulo.  Realice la inspeccion del modulo y veo una consulta SQL no me estaba arrojando los resultados esperados.  Despues de realizar el desgloce de la consulta.  Como prueba importe la BD al servidor anterior y a traves de phpmyadmin ejecute las consultas y pude observar que tengo diferentes resultados.  Dentro del analisis encontre que el servidor anterior tenia como motor de base de datos MySql 5.5.51-38.2 y el nuevo servidor tiene motor 10.0.35-MariaDB.  Mi consulta a la comunidad es que si esto es normal **y como lo podria solucionar**

La consulta que ejecuto es la siguiente:

```
SELECT temp.C3 as col1,C20 as col2,TABLA3.C2 as col3,C27 as col4 
    FROM (SELECT C3,C20 FROM TABLA1 ORDER BY C1 DESC) AS temp 
    LEFT JOIN TABLA2 ON temp.C3 = TABLA2.C4 
    LEFT JOIN TABLA3 ON TABLA2.C3 = TABLA3.C1
    WHERE TABLA2.C27 != 0 
    GROUP BY C3
    ORDER BY TABLA3.C3 ASC, col1 ASC
```

La estructura de las tablas es:

```
TABLA1
    C1 AUTO INT
    C2-C24 

TABLA2
    C1 AUTO INT
    C2-C27 

TABLA3
    C1 AUTO INT
    C2-C5
```

Si ejecuto la consulta en un motor `MYSQL` funciona adecuadamente con los resultados esperados, pero si ejecuto la consulta en un motor `MariaDB` el resultado seria como si omitiera la sentencia `ORDER BY C1 DESC` al construir la subtabla cuando se realiza el `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Javier, recuerdo un cambio de versión de SQL Server, dónde ocurría algo parecido, una inserción en tablas temporales con un orden determinado, pero cuando las recuperabas ese orden "natural" se perdía. El comportamiento que indicas que ocurre con mariaDB me parece más consistente con el estándar, la única garantía de tener un determinado orden, es configurarlo en el ORDER final.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando encontre este link

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

veo que esta es la causa